# Hardwiring the output in black box separation

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-turing-machine

In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.06750.pdf) paper, while using a diagonalization argument in Section $5$, the authors write:

> Fix some enumeration over all $poly(n)$-size quantum verifiers $M_{1},
>  M_{2},...$ which we can do because the number of such machines is
> countably infinite (by the Solovay-Kitaev theorem [15]). Some of these
> verifiers may try to decide a language by trivially “hardwiring” its
> outputs; for example, by returning 1 independent of the input. We
> start by fixing a unary language $L$ such that no machine $M_{i}$ hardwires
> the language. We can always do this because there are more languages
> than $poly(n)$-sized machines.

Maybe I am missing something very basic, but:

1. Why do we care if some of the verifiers have the output hardwired?
2. How can we find an $L$, like in the description? Why will this $L$ even be decidable? I know there are more languages than there are Turing machines; but those extra languages aren't decidable.